# USB type-c headset detection in Android

Tags: android, headset

Sorry for question. It's my first time here. I did some search on net but no result. Really need help to clarify this problem.
I have two question about USB headset detection and status query.

1. My target device is running Android version 7.1.1. The device has a USB type-c connector and support USB type-c headset. However it seems AudioService will not send intent when USB headset status changed. Does OEM have to implement his own intent for this case?
2. For traditional wire headset, I can use AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn() to check it's status. But USB type-c headset seems not work in this way. Is there any other way to get the status of USB headset?

Thanks,
Lei

Comment: Same problem here. 

I noticed that `android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY` event had been sent after unplugging the type-c headset. 

So I guess something has been implemented internal but not exposed as API.

Comment: With the Pixel 2 coming out, we've run into this issue since there's no headphone jack on that phone. We need a way to tell if the headphones are plugged in -- even through the dongle.

Answer (score 3):

As addition to EscapeArtist proposed approach, you can also listen for `UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` and `UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED` actions and check wither the current connected USB device has audio interface `UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_AUDIO`. Unfortunately, `AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` is not triggered for composite (don't sweat the wording) USB devices, such as OTG + standard USB headphones, or just USB-C headphones.

```
  override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED) {
            context.usbManager.deviceList.values.indexOfFirst {
                it.hasUsbAudioInterfaceClass()
            }.takeIf { it > -1 }?.run {
                //This attached USB device has audio interface
            }
        } else if (intent.action == UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED) {
            val device: UsbDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
            device?.apply {
                if (hasUsbAudioInterfaceClass()) {
                     //This detached USB device has audio interface
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`UsbDevice` extension function that searches wither USB device has audio dedicated audio interface.

```
fun UsbDevice.hasUsbAudioInterfaceClass(): Boolean {
     for (i in 0 until interfaceCount) {
            if (getInterface(i).interfaceClass == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_AUDIO) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Listening for detaching devices is not mandatory, since you can rely on `ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY`.

Comment: for USB-C headsets: `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` is broadcasted in Android 9, isn't in Android 7.1 (don't have Android 8 device to check). using `UsbManager` is way more reliable. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` with a filter for `AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`

Then in your receiver you can get a list of connected devices with
`devices = audioManager.getDevices(GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS)`

Then you can filter that list by looking for USB headset by checking the type:

`device.type == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_USB_HEADSET`

You might want to also look at TYPE_WIRED_HEADPHONE, TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET, TYPE_LINE_ANALOG