# How to detect Headphones for an Android Phone with no audio jack?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to detect whether user has plugged-in headphones in power port of Android phone(Moto Z Force) with no audio jack. I am looking into the [AudioDeviceInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioDeviceInfo.html) class but not sure which TYPE is suitable in this scenario.

Right now I am using following types but it's not detecting headphone.

```
if (device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADPHONES
                        || device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET
                        || device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_USB_HEADSET
                        || device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_USB_ACCESSORY
                        || device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_USB_DEVICE
                        || device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_A2DP
                        || device.getType() == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_SCO) {
                    return true;
                }
```

Comment: Did you try `audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()` ?

Comment: I've edited my question to include source code. This method `audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()` is deprecated.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583448/usb-type-c-headset-detection-in-android

Comment: The documentation's deprecation message states:

Use only to check is a headset is connected or not.

So I guess it is okay to keep using it to check whether or not a wired headset is connected, but not to check whether or not audio is being routed to it or played over it.